# How can i disyplay attributes of e.g. customers in a hidden field in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, attributes, display

im trying to disyplay earnings of a customer in a hidden field. I just did it with E-Mail of users and it worked well. The code looks like this:

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email, "E-Mail:" %>
    <%= current_user.email %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :email, value: current_user.email %>
  </div>
```

Now I´m trying to display "earnings" which is a attribute of a customer. Thats my idea but it does not work.

```
  <div class="field">
    <%=f.label :earning, "earning" %>
    <%= @customer.(:earning) %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :earning %>
  </div>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

`@customer.earning` should work if it is an attribute.

Comment: i dont really know if it is an attribute. I generated customer via scaffold and earnings was an "attribute" of a customer. If i choose your code I get:
undefinded method 'earning' .

Comment: Check the database, Rails should make a method for every column in the db, so maybe it got called something else instead?

Comment: sorry but where can i check the method of a database ?

Comment: Open up rails console, then type the name of the class (I'm assuming Customer), that should output something like `Customer(id, name, company_id)` with all of the db rows Rails knows about

Comment: sorry im very new to rails... i dont get it

Comment: read the comment in the other answer for better understanding. Maybe i have wrong models?

Comment: If you did `earnings:float` then your field is `earnings` not `earning`

Answer (score 0):

Just curious, you said

> earnings was an "attribute" of a customer

Is there a typo? Does `@customer.earnings` work?

Comment: let me explain :
i created the scaffold customer with "earnings:float". And now i created another scaffold called "request". And i want to display the value of "earnings" in a hidden field in the _form.html.erb. You understand ^^?

Comment: what I want to confirm is: you have an attribute called ```earnings```, but it seems you are trying to access ```earning```. If that's true, you should replace ```earning``` with ```earnings``` in your posted code.